# Container height no longer than screen-header

Tags: html, css

I asked a question today about good and bad practises in CSS/HTML/jQuery and when it is appropriate to use jQuery to set container dimensions. I got some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447547/how-bad-is-it-to-set-div-height-and-width-with-jquery)

So, understanding that jQuery is not the best option, I decided to ask maybe some of you can give some input about this "problem"

So, I have a page put together with php. I have one header for all of my pages and content is being changed with php (I am saying this only to let you guys know that wrapping header and div in one container is not an option):

```
include ("header.php");
include ("$lang/$section.php");
include ("footer.php");
```

I have a header with fixed hight (100px + 100px margin-bottom) and after that I have a div which on screens smaller than 768px(height) I want to be no longer than the remaining space. If the screen is larger, I want my div to be

```
max-height: 420px;
```

with

```
padding: 100px 0;
```

Inside of this div I have 3 floated columns. I need them to fill the space in the parent div.

What I would usually do is- use jQuery and calculate screen height and subtract header height and all the margins and paddings. But as I've learned today, that is not a good practise.

So, to wrap it up: I NEED THE DIV TO FILL THE SPACE BETWEEN HEADER AND BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN FOR VIEWPORT HEIGHT SMALLER THAN 768px. MAX-HEIGHT FOR THIS DIV IS 420px. With jQuery it is super easy but I can't figure out the clean css way.

Maybe some of you have an idea?
Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/66ahsb5s/), so you guys don't have to type out all of the code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where's the HTML code?

Comment: In the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/66ahsb5s/

Comment: not clear by ur question what u wan achieve?

Comment: what about `height: calc(100vh - 200px)`? `vh` is viewport height and we remove the 200px from the header using the `calc()` function.

Comment: What is the browser support? I haven't seen this solution!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do? Do you actually mean you want the content container to use 100% of the screen height, minus the height of the header? Question title is misleading...

Comment: Yes! For screens smaller than 768px. Otherwise max-height 420px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc()` and `vh` (viewport height).

`calc()` browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

`vh` browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

So we use `calc(100vh - 200px)` being `100vh` the height of the viewport and `200px` the height of the header.

Also, we add a media query so that when the screen is bigger than 768px height we limit the height to 420px.

Try this:

```css
header { height: 100px; background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 100px;  box-sizing: border-box; }

section { width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 200px); padding: 50px 0; background: yellow; box-sizing: border-box; }

.col1, .col2, .col3 { float: left; width: 33%; }

.colPadding { padding: 25px; background: blue; }

.cb { width: 100%; height: 1px; clear: both; }

body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 768px) {
  section {
    max-height: 420px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
    This is my header with 100px bottom margin
</header>
<section>
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="colPadding">
            section with padding: 50px 0; and max-height: 420px;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="colPadding">
            Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        <div class="colPadding">
            Column 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cb"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! This is awesome! Didn't know about calc().

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a shot with CSS3 flex-box model and screen media queries. Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/kdsax8th/).

I used 300px instead of 764px for the fiddle. (you can change it if you want, I just used 300px so that it's easier to test)

**Applied CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; } /* force sizing based on border */
body {
    display: flex; /* flex for body since wrapping header and section is not allowed */
    flex-flow: column wrap; 
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* make header size fixed */
}
section {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 420px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background: yellow;
    /* to occupy remaining space */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    /* for columns inside to occupy full width */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    /* for immediate children to stretch to max height possible */
    align-items: stretch;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    float: left;
    /* to occupy remaining width */
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.colPadding {
    padding: 25px;
    background: blue;
}
.cb {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    clear: both;
}

/* Custom CSS */
/* style to apply when the screen is less than or equal to 300px (you can change this to 768px) */
@media screen and ( max-height: 300px ){ 
    body {
        height: 100vh; /* for body to have a size of the full screen */
    }
    header {
        margin: 0px; /* remove margin bottom */
    }
    section {
        padding: 0px; /* remove margin bottom and top/bottom padding */
        margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

More on CSS3 flex-box [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thank you for your input! This time I can not use this in my project because of IE support, but I like the idea.

Comment: No problem, hope it does help you in the future though :)